# rostopic echo to webpage

Tags: ros, rostopic-echo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can iI export the output from rostopic echo (for example the battery level) to a webpage?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64292/rostopic-echo-to-webpage/) by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can look at [rosbridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbridge_suite) for this.
Or write a node yourself that generates a html file with the level.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on 2013-06-05**:
Excellent! Thank you for this information. I just checked it out. Does it run with ros electric, too?
also, Do you have any experience with Json? What the structure of such a file be, for example to get the data from rostopic echo battery?